# jquery waypoint infinite scroll not working

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to implement simple infinite scroll for div elements using Waypoints.
so I followed their tutorial and came up with very simple markup, but it doesn't work.
any suggestions?

code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class=" js flexbox opacity"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<title>Infinite SCroll - test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="infinite.js"></script>


    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script>
        function infiniteExample() {
        var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
          element: $('.infinite-container')[0]
        })
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>



<div class="infinite-container waypoint">
  <div class="infinite-item">1</div>
  <div class="infinite-item">2</div>
  <div class="infinite-item">3</div>
  <div class="infinite-item">4</div>
  <div class="infinite-item">5</div>
  <div class="infinite-item">6</div>
  <div class="infinite-item">7</div>
  <div class="infinite-item">8</div>
  <div class="infinite-item">9</div>
  <div class="infinite-item">10</div>
<div class="infinite-item">11</div><div class="infinite-item">12</div><div class="infinite-item">13</div><div class="infinite-item">14</div><div class="infinite-item">15</div><div class="infinite-item">16</div><div class="infinite-item">17</div><div class="infinite-item">18</div><div class="infinite-item">19</div><div class="infinite-item">20</div><div class="infinite-item">21</div><div class="infinite-item">22</div><div class="infinite-item">23</div><div class="infinite-item">24</div><div class="infinite-item">25</div><div class="infinite-item">26</div><div class="infinite-item">27</div><div class="infinite-item">28</div><div class="infinite-item">29</div><div class="infinite-item">30</div><div class="infinite-item">31</div><div class="infinite-item">32</div><div class="infinite-item">33</div><div class="infinite-item">34</div><div class="infinite-item">35</div><div class="infinite-item">36</div><div class="infinite-item">37</div><div class="infinite-item">38</div><div class="infinite-item">39</div><div class="infinite-item">40</div></div>
 </div>



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `<a>` tag with with the attributes `class="infinite-more-link"` and `href="/next/page"` at the end:

```
<a class="infinite-more-link" href="/next/page">More</a>
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class=" js flexbox opacity">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>Infinite SCroll - test</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="infinite.js"></script>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script>
    function infiniteExample() {
      var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
        element: $('.infinite-container')[0]
      })
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="infinite-container waypoint">
    <div class="infinite-item">1</div>
    <div class="infinite-item">2</div>
    <div class="infinite-item">3</div>
    <div class="infinite-item">4</div>
    <div class="infinite-item">5</div>
    <div class="infinite-item">6</div>
    <div class="infinite-item">7</div>
    <div class="infinite-item">8</div>
    <div class="infinite-item">9</div>
    <div class="infinite-item">10</div>
  </div>

  <a class="infinite-more-link" href="/next/page">More</a>

</body>
</html>
```

And then you have to prepare the `/next/page` for Waypoints to retrieve data from server. It will return something like this:

```
<div class="infinite-item">11</div>
<div class="infinite-item">12</div>
<div class="infinite-item">13</div>
<div class="infinite-item">14</div>
<div class="infinite-item">15</div>
<div class="infinite-item">16</div>
<div class="infinite-item">17</div>
<div class="infinite-item">18</div>
<div class="infinite-item">19</div>
<div class="infinite-item">20</div>
```

Newly loaded items are appended to the `infinite-container`.